# How to store coordinates into different variables??

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use `getBounds()` in my google map script code to obtain latitude & longitude bounds of current viewport.
I use `getSouthWest()` & `getNorthEast()` to obtain the position of  south-west & north-east bounds of this map.

After adding the google map,I gave the following code inside the Javascript tags.

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
```

When I used `alert()` to display both of the variables,I successfully obtained the bounds.

`alert(southWest)` gives `SouthWest: (-2.871967531323266, 57.88463437500002)` as output.

`alert(northEast)` gives `NorthEast: (18.75527829568889, 97.43541562500002)` as output.

I'm singing hallelujah on fourth of July. :) :) :P

Now I am trying to store these values into 4 different variables.

I want to store `-2.871967531323266` into `variable w`, `57.88463437500002` into `variable x`, `18.75527829568889` into `variable y`, `97.43541562500002` into `variable z`.

Is the output that I got an array??? How can I do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object:

```
var Obj = {
'w' : -2.871967531323266,
'x' : 57.88463437500002,
'y' : 18.75527829568889,
'z' : 97.43541562500002
};

Obj['w']; //-2.871967531323266
Obj.w; //-2.871967531323266
```

Objects can also be declared one key at a time:

```
var Obj = {};

Obj['w'] = -2.871967531323266;
Obj.x = -57.88463437500002;
```

edit: You should study objects more closely, they're fundamental to Javascript. It is returning an object. You should also use `console.log()` not `alert()`, as it gives the full picture.

You must run the .lat() and .lng() functions on the returned object to get the latitude and longitude, as such:

```
  var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
  var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();

  var contentString = 'New north-east corner: ' + ne.lat() + ', ' + ne.lng() + '<br>' +
      'New south-west corner: ' + sw.lat() + ', ' + sw.lng();
```

Comment: I know thats the way to do it. My question is how to do it. The value contained in southWest is SouthWest: (-2.871967531323266, 57.88463437500002). My question is, is it an array? How can I fetch the values -2.871967531323266 & 57.88463437500002 from the variable southWest & store it into two different new variables.??? @James G.

Comment: Well....I ain't a JavaScript guy. This is the first time I messing with this heck.